# Getting errors using actionPerformed and actionListener

Tags: java, action, actionlistener

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't find anything that works. I made a test class, so I can give an example.

```
public class Action implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ...
    JButton b1 = new JButton("action");
    b1.setVisible(true);
    b1.setSize(100,30);  //Cannot instantiate the type
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener());         
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    //I get an error when I put "}" to close the brackets

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to implement ActionListener if you're only using it for the JButton, but you do need to instantiate an ActionListener within the addActionListener method.

Here's my take on it.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Action {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JButton b1 = new JButton("action");
    b1.setVisible(true);
    b1.setSize(100,30);  //Cannot instantiate the type
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Some action.

                }

            });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it, one question though: is it better to use imports for a specific object? example: import javax.swing.JButton;, and javax.swing.JFrame;, and the like, instead of: import javax.swing.*;? Thanks again!

Comment: If you're using a couple of imports only you should just use those import, but if it starts to get cluttered, it's worth the memory to use the multiple import statement.